# Why do i get 404 error in python requests even if page exists?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-404

I wanted to create a program that checks a nickname taken or not, but i get 404 error even if that page exists or not. I assume its about the armory.warmane link but couldn't figure it out.

Here's my code.

```
import requests

data = ["some data","some data","some data"]

a = 0

for i in data:
    response = requests.get(f"https://armory.warmane.com/character/{data[a]}/Icecrown/summary")
    if response.status_code == 404:
        print(f"{data[a]} is not taken")
    a += 1
```

Comment: Can you share URL, that respond with 404 in your program but responds correctly in browser?

Comment: Are you sure the `/Icecrown` part of the URL is supposed to be there? What does it mean?

Comment: @Eugenij This a game website. Heres a working url. 
https://armory.warmane.com/character/Xodia/Icecrown/summary

Comment: @Karl Knechtel 
Yes '/Icecrown' part needs to be there. There are few servers like Icecrown, Frostmourne etc. This part defines which server is character in. And summary part is like the profile.

Comment: "Heres a working url." Does the code work if you hard-code that URL? Did you consider the possibility that in your actual program, the `data` doesn't look like what you expect? As an aside: when you write `for i in data:`, what do you think that actually means? In particular, what values do you expect `i` to have? Do you see a way to use this information to simplify your code? If not, you should look up how it actually works.

Comment: Even this doesn't work..

'print(requests.get("http://armory.warmane.com"))
<Response [404]>'

Comment: @Karl Kechtel in data there are 1000 lines of does look like this
'''
data = [
"Olivia",
"Emma",
"Ava",
"Charlotte",
"Luna",
"Ella"]
'''
and yes i tried hard-code, the site doesnt even respond to https://armor.warmane.com

Comment: So the problem is that you cannot access this website at all from your code? Can you access *any* website from your code? If you can, then it's the headers issue described in the answers; depending on the website, you may need to use relatively specific headers. The idea is that the website actively does not want bots to connect, and you need to identify your code *convincingly* as "I'm a web browser". But if you can't connect to any website from Python, check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are not getting this is this site returns a web page even if the user name does not exist. 404 error means the service is not returning any response.

If you can observe between this tag it will return page not found text which means it returns a web page. What you can do is find the "Page not found" text inside the returned webpage.

use [string.find()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) to find "Page not found" text in the returned response html page. use `response.text` to convert the response to Unicode string.

use `headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom'}` as headers and pass the header object defined as a parameter.

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Yes i totally understand what u are saying and you are %100 right, i will review my code. But this solution does not solve me getting 404 error.

Comment: Hi Fixed my answer. Sorry haven't read it fully @malcom32

Comment: Glad that i could help you. Please accept my answer and upvote

Comment: @malcom32 will you please be able to accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I was building a same solution (trying to find a short, available character name) and came up with this full solution:

```py
# %%
import requests
from string import ascii_lowercase
import itertools


def iter_all_strings():
    for size in itertools.count(1):
        for s in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=size):
            yield "".join(s)


def urls():
    for infix in iter_all_strings():
        yield f"https://armory.warmane.com/character/{infix}/Icecrown/summary"


# %%
with open("output.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for url in urls():
        resp = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Custom"})
        if (
            resp.text.find(
                "The character you are looking for does not exist or does not meet the minimum required level."
            )
            > 0
        ):
            print(url)
            f.write(url + "\n")
            f.flush()
    print("done")
```

I'm running it in vscode, using the built-in Jupyter extension (that's the `# %%` bits - they split a `.py` file into 'cells')

Answer (score 0):

Use this header in your response:

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}
response = self.get_response(url, headers)
```

Adjust the header based on ur OS.